# How to define global SESSION in CakePHP's AppController?

Tags: php, cakephp

I am using CakePHP 3.3

My Controller:

```
class ConfigsController extends AppController
{

    public $session;

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();
        $this->loadComponent('CheckAuthUserSession');

        $this->session = $this->request->session();
    }
}
```

I have this line below in every controller of my project

```
$this->session = $this->request->session();
```

Is there a way to define this in AppController's initialize() and then I can access it by `parent::session`? Or anywhere else which makes it global.

Answer (score 1):

Aaaha found the solution

My AppController:

```
class AppController extends Controller
{
    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');

        $this->session = $this->request->session();

    }
}
```

and in all other controllers I just use `$this->session` to do `$this->session->read()` or `$this->session->write()`